# Align and Orign from famo.us example acts differently as in example

Tags: javascript, famo.us

I copied the example-code from http://famo.us/university/famous-102/transitionables/1/ ,but get different behaviour in all different browsers (used Chrome 35.0.1916.153 m, Opera 22.0.1471.70, IE 11.0.9600, Firefox 30 (here even the click does not work)).

The greenBackground, redBackground and the toggleSwitch are NOT put on top of each other as in the example, but in the browsers they are put below each other.

I can align them proberly when I change the origin and align parameters, but this should not be necessary.

Any idea, why the behaviour is different ?

Cheers, Rob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to a lack of the famous.css file.  Try including the CDN'd version of the css to your project. CDN link below.

http://code.famo.us/famous/0.2/famous.css